# Group By Count and Total Count

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, select, group-by

I am trying to figure out how can I get following result by query but unable to do the same.

Table Name: ProductMaster

```
ProductCode   Quantity   EntryDate
A1            10         10/03/2015
A1            10         15/03/2015
A2            10         18/03/2015
A2            10         25/03/2015
A1            10         10/04/2015
A2            10         15/04/2015
```

I want to get result as
If I select March month, result should be as:

```
ProductCode   MonthCount   TotalCount
A1            20           30         
A2            20           30
```

If I select April month, result should be as:

```
ProductCode   MonthCount   TotalCount
A1            10           30         
A2            10           30
```

My Query:

```
SELECT ProductCode, SUM(Quantity) 
FROM ProductMaster
WHERE DATEPART(MONTH, EntryDate) = @Month
GROUP BY ProductCode
```

Where `@month = 3` or `4`, based on input.

Additionally, How can i get the count of productcode.
For `Month = 3`

```
ProductCode   MonthCount   TotalCount
A1            2            3         
A2            2            3
```

Comment: Shouldnt total count on your first example be 40? and on your second example be 20?

Comment: Total count is also group by productcode. Hence if you check total count for A1 is 30.

Comment: Is the EntryDate column a DateTime?  What query(s) have you tried to get the desired result?

Comment: @AdamPorad: Question has been edited. Here i am able to get the count for the month but how to get the total count

Comment: @mureinik: How can do the additional part of my question. Please check my revised question.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could use a `case` expression based on `@Month`:

```
SELECT   ProductCode, 
         SUM (CASE WHEN MONTH(EntryDate) = @Month THEN Quantity ELSE 0 END) 
           AS MonthCount,
         SUM (Quantity) AS TotalConount
FROM     ProductMaster
GROUP BY ProductCode
```

EDIT:
To answer the edited question, you can use the same technique with `count` instead of `sum`:

```
SELECT   ProductCode, 
         COUNT (CASE WHEN MONTH(EntryDate) = @Month THEN Quantity ELSE NULL END) 
           AS MonthCount,
         COUNT (*) AS TotalConount
FROM     ProductMaster
GROUP BY ProductCode
```

Comment: OK. I was close but only able to figure out to achieve the same. Great help to me. Thankssss.

Answer (score 2):

Here is a solution using a [Common Table Expression](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190766%28v=sql.105%29.aspx) (CTE).  This query will get the results for all months in the same resultset.  If you only need one month you can add a WHERE clause and filter on MonthNumber for just the month you desire.

```
;WITH cteProductMasterByMonth AS
(
    SELECT ProductCode, DATEPART(MONTH, EntryDate) as MonthNumber, SUM(Quantity) as MonthCount
    FROM #ProductMaster
    GROUP BY ProductCode, DATEPART(MONTH, EntryDate)
)
SELECT ProductCode, MonthCount, SUM(MonthCount) OVER(PARTITION BY ProductCode) AS TotalCount
FROM cteProductMasterByMonth
ORDER BY MonthNumber, ProductCode
```

I tested this on [<kbd>SqlFiddle</kbd>](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/e9bc6/1)

Note: If the EntryDate values spans multiple years and you want to the results for each month-year pair, then you will need to add an additional condition to in the CTE query to group by `DATEPART(YEAR, EntryDate)` as well and maybe a YearNumber field similar to the MonthNumber field in the select clause.