# Calculate total affiliated count per user

Tags: mysql, sql, group-by

[image]I've been looking for a simple SQL query to solve a very simple problem. I have been running a very simple social sharing campaign and we have a mysql database with 2 fields:  email and AffiliateID

```
SELECT
users.Email, users.ID,
users.AffiliateID,
Count(users.AffiliateID) as afid
from users
order by afid desc
```

When I run this query it only returns 1 record with the correct count only the highest count.

What I would like is a list of all the users sorted by the people who have the most 'affiliateID' records in the database.

That will tell us who to give the first prize in the sharing contest to.

Here are some similar questions in here but those solutions don't seem to apply for this situation.

What I would like is a descending output of all the users in the system RANKED by their parent (sponsor) so we can build something akin to a 'leader board'

[Group By Count and Total Count](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29802979/group-by-count-and-total-count)

[MySQL: Count total in Group by Query](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52290549/mysql-count-total-in-group-by-query)

Thank you for your help!

here's updated query

```
select u.Email, AffiliateID, count(u.AffiliateID) as afid
from users u
where SiteID=17
group by u.Email
order by afid desc
```

this generates the image above...

but that's not what I need.  What I need is for the 509218 user to show up first and then the count of how many users he's referred followed by the next user 5dd..  then in third place and fourth place would be 471 and 472 with a tie.

Comment: Still struggling? See https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query, and remember to include a Primary Key (although I suspect this advice will be entirely ignored)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should add `group by` (to get results per user) clause:

```
select u.AffiliateID, count(u.Email) as afid
from users u
group by u.AffiliateID
order by afid desc
```

If you need more data from your `users` table you can `join` result of the query below with `users` table:

```
select u.ID, u.Email, t.afid
from users u
join (
  select AffiliateID, count(ID) as afid
  from users
  group by AffiliateID
) t on u.ID = t.AffiliateID
order by t.afid desc
```

Comment: Thanks - that got me closer to the goal but its not what i'm looking for.... I UPLOADED picture to illustrate...

Each user has an ID and an AffiliateID

Say I refer you my ID is 5092... etc.  as in the picture above (that's my ID)

in the AffiliateID column of your record, my ID is placed.

What I want is kind of like a reflexive statement that shows the ranking of the top affiliates.

Comment: Your query only returns the 1 value because its not actually counting WHO has the most votes. Am I making sense?  What I'd like the output to be is the ID of the person who has the most count of AffiliateID records. Am I making sense?  Its a leader board.

Comment: @Viktor you mean you need the person with the most affiliated count? then see the updated answer

Comment: yes - I need the list of people with the most referred affiliates. not just 1 but a list ordered by people who referred the most.  your updated query still returns the same picture I posted above.

Comment: @Viktor: sorry, I don't fully understand you, please, post some sample data and the desired output based on it

Comment: refresh the post... I posted a screenshot image of sample data.

Comment: its still showing afid with 1's in all the columns.

Comment: my original query which only returns 1 value gives the right # - there are 3607 records where the Affiliate ID is 50912830f598

Comment: @Viktor: so you have different emails corresponding to the same affiliated_id. you see, it is kind of hard to work with incomplete data (no `u.ID` and `u.Email`) and no desired output, a lot of guessing is involved. Updated the answer

Comment: To clarify. Every user has an ID. once they refer someone their sponsor's ID gets stored in the AffiliateID Column.  What I need a query that shows the ID's of the top people who referred other people. My ID = 50921830f598 and I referred the most - a total of 3607 in other words my ID appears in OTHER people's Affiliate ID records more than anyone else.

Comment: YES!!!! that's exactly the answer. So, how can we clean up this post so its archived correctly?